# modify regex to include the backslash and single quote (so that backslash behaves as an escaping character)

Tags: c++, regex, escaping

I have the following string:

```
arg1('value1') arg2('value '')2') arg3('value\'3')
```

The regex to extract the value looks like:

```
boost::regex re_arg_values("('[^']*(?:''[^']*)*')");
```

Now this regex is not able to extract **'value\'3'**. How can I modify the regex to consider \' inside the parenthesis as well.

FYI. The value can contain spaces, special characters, and also tabs. The code is in CPP.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Like this - [`('[^']*(?:''[^']*)*'[^)]*)`](https://regex101.com/r/d3nOG2/1)?

Comment: Writing from a mobile, please check `"('[^\\\\']*(?:(?:''|\\\\.)[^\\\\']*)*')"`. If you have a string with line breaks replace `.` with `[\\s\\S]`. Please note that copy-paste from SO comments may result in garbage chars may be introduced, check for invisible chars if you do that.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, 
It is not working

Comment: Did you repost the same question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47768441/modify-regex-to-include-opening-and-closing-parenthesis? See https://ideone.com/jvICdg

Comment: no its different

Comment: I just obtained `'value1'`, `'value '')2'` and `'user\'~!@#$%^&*_~!@#$%^&"*_-=+[{]}\|;:<.>?21**()**'`, see https://ideone.com/jvICdg (using the solution I posted [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47325086/modify-regex-to-include-the-backslash-and-single-quote-so-that-backslash-behave?noredirect=1#comment81609369_47325086)). How come these are different questions?

Comment: Ok, do you mean the only difference is that you do not know how to match parentheses? See https://ideone.com/NeDQ8N

Comment: BTW, as you see in [my demo](https://ideone.com/jvICdg), my suggestion above works well. Most probably, your input string has got no backslashes (as most probably you defined them as a single ``\`` in a regular string literal). Use raw string literals

Comment: It has got the backslash, maybe its the cpp version that is not supporting the regex.

Comment: Wait, if you are using Boost, your CPP version has got nothing to do with that.

Comment: Please share the *reproducible* code you are having.

Answer (score 0):

```
boost::regex re_arg_values( "\('([^'\\]|''|\\.)*'\)" );
```

The `\('` and `'\)` match the bounds.

The `(`, `|`, and `)*` for matching any of the given patterns

The `[^'\\]` matches normal characters.

The `''` matches a pair of single quotes.

The `\\.` matches any escaped character (including stacked backslashes).