# modify regex to include comma

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I have the following string:

```
arg1('value1') arg2('value '')2') arg3('user\'~!@#$%^&*_~!@#$%^&"*_-=+[{]}\|;:<.>?21')
```

The regex to extract the value looks like:

```
boost::regex re_arg_values("('[^']*(?:''[^']*)*'[^)]*)");
```

The above regex properly extracts the values. BUT when I include a comma , the code fails. For eg:

```
  arg1('value1') arg2('value '')2') arg3('user\'~!@#$%^&*_~!@#$%^&"*_-=+[{]}\|;:<.>?21**,**')
```

How shall I modify this regex to include the comma?
FYI. The value can contain spaces, special characters, and also tabs. The code is in CPP.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure, are you just after `re_arg_values("(\('[^']*(?:''[^']*)*'[^)]*\))")`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew,
I am preferring modifying this : boost::regex re_arg_values("('[^']*(?:''[^']*)*'[^)]*)");

And this is not able to include comma or a closed parenthesis. Can you please help me out?

Comment: Actually, this is accepting :

arg('user()~!@#$%^&*_-=+[{]}\\|;:2"<.\'>?')
But it is not working for ","(comma). Is there any way I can explicitly state in the regex to accept that??

Comment: Please pay attention to the backslashes. When you use them in a regular string literal, you must double backslashes to define literal backslashes. Now, I cannot help you much if you do not provide an **exact fiddle/code snippet you are testing now** (you will be constantly writing back that it does not work) if your string literal is written with single backslashes, and you are not using raw string literals.

Comment: Your current `"('[^']*(?:''[^']*)*'[^)]*)"` pattern does not match outer parentheses because it is a capturing group now. You may remove the outer parentheses, and you will still get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

I'd not use a regex here.

The goal MUST be to parse values, and no doubt they will have useful values, that you need interpreted.

I'd devise a datastructure like:

```
#include <map>

namespace Config {
    using Key = std::string;
    using Value = boost::variant<int, std::string, bool>;
    using Setting = std::pair<Key, Value>;
    using Settings = std::map<Key, Value>;
}
```

For this you can write 1:1 a parser using Boost Spirit:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_pair.hpp>

namespace Parser {
    using It = std::string::const_iterator;
    using namespace Config;
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

    using Skip = qi::blank_type;
    qi::rule<It, std::string()>   quoted_   = "'" >> *(
            "'" >> qi::char_("'") // double ''
          | '\\' >> qi::char_     // any character escaped
          | ~qi::char_("'")       // non-quotes
       ) >> "'";
    qi::rule<It, Key()>           key_      = +qi::char_("a-zA-Z0-9_"); // for example
    qi::rule<It, Value()>         value_    = qi::int_ | quoted_ | qi::bool_;
    qi::rule<It, Setting(), Skip> setting_  = key_ >> '(' >> value_ >> ')';
    qi::rule<It, Settings()>      settings_ = qi::skip(qi::blank) [*setting_];
}
```

Note how this

- interprets non-string values correctly
- specifies what keys look like and parses them too
- interprets string escapes, so the `Value` in the map contains the "real" string, after un-escaping
- ignores whitespace outside values (use `space_type` if you want to ignore newlines as whitespace as well)

You can use it like:

```
int main() {
    std::string const input = R"(    arg1('value1') arg2('value '')2') arg3('user\'~!@#$%^&*_~!@#$%^&"*_-=+[{]}\|;:<.>?21**,**'))";

    Config::Settings map;
    if (parse(input.begin(), input.end(), Parser::settings_, map)) {
        for(auto& entry : map)
            std::cout << "config setting {" << entry.first << ", " << entry.second << "}\n";
    }
}
```

Which prints

```
config setting {arg1, value1}
config setting {arg2, value ')2}
config setting {arg3, user'~!@#$%^&*_~!@#$%^&"*_-=+[{]}|;:<.>?21**,**}
```

### Live Demo

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/038f97bf8ef7ca36)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <map>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_pair.hpp>

namespace Config {
    using Key = std::string;
    using Value = boost::variant<int, std::string, bool>;
    using Setting = std::pair<Key, Value>;
    using Settings = std::map<Key, Value>;
}

namespace Parser {
    using It = std::string::const_iterator;
    using namespace Config;
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

    using Skip = qi::blank_type;
    qi::rule<It, std::string()>   quoted_   = "'" >> *(
            "'" >> qi::char_("'") // double ''
          | '\\' >> qi::char_     // any character escaped
          | ~qi::char_("'")       // non-quotes
       ) >> "'";
    qi::rule<It, Key()>           key_      = +qi::char_("a-zA-Z0-9_"); // for example
    qi::rule<It, Value()>         value_    = qi::int_ | quoted_ | qi::bool_;
    qi::rule<It, Setting(), Skip> setting_  = key_ >> '(' >> value_ >> ')';
    qi::rule<It, Settings()>      settings_ = qi::skip(qi::blank) [*setting_];
}

int main() {
    std::string const input = R"(    arg1('value1') arg2('value '')2') arg3('user\'~!@#$%^&*_~!@#$%^&"*_-=+[{]}\|;:<.>?21**,**'))";

    Config::Settings map;
    if (parse(input.begin(), input.end(), Parser::settings_, map)) {
        for(auto& entry : map)
            std::cout << "config setting {" << entry.first << ", " << entry.second << "}\n";
    }
}
```

### BONUS

For comparison, here's the "same" but using regex:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ae17bfb9b6bb39c9)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

namespace Config {
    using Key = std::string;
    using RawValue = std::string;
    using Settings = std::map<Key, RawValue>;

    Settings parse(std::string const& input) {
        Settings settings;

        boost::regex re(R"((\w+)\(('.*?')\))");
        auto f = boost::make_regex_iterator(input, re);

        for (auto& match : boost::make_iterator_range(f, {}))
            settings.emplace(match[1].str(), match[2].str());

        return settings;
    }
}

int main() {
    std::string const input = R"(    arg1('value1') arg2('value '')2') arg3('user\'~!@#$%^&*_~!@#$%^&"*_-=+[{]}\|;:<.>?21**,**'))";

    Config::Settings map = Config::parse(input);
    for(auto& entry : map)
        std::cout << "config setting {" << entry.first << ", " << entry.second << "}\n";
}
```

Prints

```
config setting {arg1, 'value1'}
config setting {arg2, 'value ''}
config setting {arg3, 'user\'~!@#$%^&*_~!@#$%^&"*_-=+[{]}\|;:<.>?21**,**'}
```

Notes:

- it no longer interprets and converts any values
- it no longer processes escapes
- it requires an additional runtime library dependency on boost_regex

Comment: Added a [bonus implementation](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ae17bfb9b6bb39c9) using Boost Regex for fair comparison